How to use array as input in terragrunt which accepts only as string in terraform
Describe the bug
we have terraform code for key vault (Azure) in which object Id is string for access policies . but wanted to give as array i.e multiple user id (object id) in single object id.
Steps To Reproduce the issue.
main.tf :
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                        = "examplekeyvault"
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false
  sku_name                    = "standard"

  dynamic "access_policy" {
    for_each = var.access_policies
    content {
      tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
      object_id = access_policy.value["object_id"]
      secret_permissions = access_policy.value["secret_permissions"]
      key_permissions = access_policy.value["key_permissions"]
    }
  }
}

variables.tf:
variable "access_policies" {
  type = set(
  object({
    object_id = string,
    secret_permissions = set(string),
    key_permissions = set(string)
    })
  )
}

keyvault > terragrunt.hcl :
    input ={
    access_policies = [

    { object_id = "xyz", secret_permissions = ["Get","Set"], key_permissions = ["Get"] },
    { object_id = "abc", secret_permissions = ["Get"], key_permissions = ["Get"] } ]

above code is working fine
Expecting behavior as below ...
i want to keep object id as array and secret permission and key permission in 1 line ...something like below which is not working even if keep object_id = set(string) in variables.tf
    { object_id = ["xyz","abc"], secret_permissions = ["Get","Set"], key_permissions = ["Get"] },

in fact i wanted to keep this object ids as common in global_var.hcl file so that all environment can use have same object_id rather than local terragrunt file.
===================================================================
i tried with set(string) for object id in varaibles.tf file as below , but still issue exist.
ERROR - object_id must be string
variables.tf:
variable "access_policies" {
  type = set(
    object({
    object_id = set(string),
    secret_permissions = set(string),
    key_permissions = set(string)
    })
  )
}


Where is the error coming from? Are you using modules? If so, does the same variable exist in both the root and child modules?

Error is from -- dynamic "access_policy" >  "object ID"    it is expecting only string  ...

You can try with object_id = ["xyz"]. But that should only fix one part of the problem.

I have already tried that , it shows  "ERROR - object_id must be string " , it is not accepting in array for object_ID.. i have edited that in question body ...

Ok, well that's because the object_id is singular, i.e, that means it can only accept a single value.

yah ... even i am in same page .. But how to make it accept array of object ids ..may be we can use for loop twice ...not sure how to place in the code

@Marko E - Any idea on this ?


I have already tried that , it shows "ERROR - object_id must be string " , it is not accepting in array for object_ID.. i have edited that in question body

To handle multiple object_ids within the constraints of Terraform, you need to use a nested loop approach.

Thanks @Marko_E, nested loop involves creating a dynamic block for each access policy and then another dynamic block for each object_id within that policy.

Terraform Configuration
variables.tf:
variable "access_policies" {
  type = list(
    object({
      object_ids         = list(string),
      secret_permissions = list(string),
      key_permissions    = list(string)
    })
  )
}


main.tf:
resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                        = "examplekeyvault"
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  enabled_for_disk_encryption = true
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  soft_delete_retention_days  = 7
  purge_protection_enabled    = false
  sku_name                    = "standard"

  dynamic "access_policy" {
    for_each = flatten([for policy in var.access_policies : [
      for object_id in policy.object_ids : {
        object_id          = object_id
        secret_permissions = policy.secret_permissions
        key_permissions    = policy.key_permissions
      }
    ]])
    content {
      tenant_id          = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
      object_id          = access_policy.value["object_id"]
      secret_permissions = access_policy.value["secret_permissions"]
      key_permissions    = access_policy.value["key_permissions"]
    }
  }
}

global_var.hcl:
access_policies = [
  { object_ids = ["xyz", "abc"], secret_permissions = ["Get", "Set"], key_permissions = ["Get"] }
]


The outer dynamic block iterates each policy in var.access_policies. For each policy, the inner dynamic block iterates each object_id in the policy's object_ids.

This nested structure works on each object_id individually within its policy.


Result:


above code worked, but I have error .
Error: Invalid value for input variable
on variables.tf line 28:
28: variable "access_policies" {
Unsuitable value for var.access_policies set using the
TF_VAR_access_policies environment variable: element 0: attribute "object_id": string required.
I have not configured TF_VAR_access_policies variable anywhere in my terraform code or in CI/CD pipeline

Check how did you pass the Object_id in the variables because it is missing.

variables are passed via terragrunt.hcl file
